# ASP.NET MVC failed to execute the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection ne peut pas être converti en [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Le type A provient de 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' dans le contexte 'Default' à l'emplacement 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Le type B provient de 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' dans le contexte 'Default' à l'emplacement 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\feb824cb\547a5d00\assembly\dl3\04741f71\76316499_ad7cd101\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

When I tried to launch an application this exception was thrown, I just updated the entity framework and installed the Jquery and bootstrap from the Nuget and I allow the installer to modify the `web.config`. I don't know what this error refers to?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue using Visual studio 2013 and to solve it, I modified the webConfig file in the view folder as the following:
I replaced the System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup version = 2.0.0.0 by version=4.0.0.0, and the 2 last ones by version =3.0.0.0 and all worked fine.